# threading is not working properly with SQL requests in Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, multithreading, pyodbc

i have a program that get api requests then store it in local Microsoft sql Database
the function that i'm trying to execute using threading does the following:

1.make api request and get the response

2.using the response data make 10 more api requests

3.split and store the data into 1 dictionary and 2 lists

4.make sql request and execute it

the lists contains dictionaries each dictionary is a row in database and i'm storing on 3 different tables that connected through keys
the problem is the first table got the full information but the 2nd and 3rd have missing information like i have 150 rows in the first table but only 34 rows in the second and 30 in the third they should be 150 rows,300 rows and 1500 rows

i tried to make a copy for my code that is easy to understand

```py
def multithreading(people):
    names = []
    for person in people:
        names.append(person['name'])
    with Pool() as pool:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            pool.starmap(get_info, names)
def get_info(name):
    info = apirequest(name)
    company, projects, contribution = more_info(info['ID'])
    save_in_database(company,projects,contribution)

def more_info(ID):
    response = apirequest(ID)
    processes_information(response)
```

and for the code that saves to database

```py
def save_in_database(company,projects,contribution):
    keys,values = (company , 'dict')
    insert('company.dbo',keys,values)
    keys,values =(projects , 'list of dict')
    insert('projects.dbo',keys,values)
    keys,values = (contribution , 'list of dict')
    insert('contribution.dbo',keys,values)
def insert(db, columns, values):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES  %s  " % (db, columns, values)
    print(sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
```

should i provide any more information ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post some source code? Is there a specific problem with your current implementation? What have you tried so far?

For a start, you could have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the problem i have more than 5 functions in use in 4 different models i'll put the saving to sql function and see if this help or i should put everything

Comment: Are you being careful to ensure that threads do not share a connection?

Comment: will i think that is maybe the problem because i establish the connection at the start of the program before threading begin should i make a function to start connection and call it in the threads??